# Laravel-5 whereHas Clause dosen't work as expected

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have `categories` and `products` tables. They are related with Many to Many relationships.. I want to get products by categories and selected price range but whereHas clause dosen't work

```
$products = Product::whereHas('categories',function ($query) use ($slug){
$query->where('category_slug',$slug);
})->whereBetween('price',[100,200])->get();
```

Category Model;

```
public function products(){
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product','category_product','category_id','product_id');
 }
```

Product Model;

```
public function categories() {
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category','category_product','product_id','category_id');
    }
```

[image: categories table]

So, what is my mistake in here ?

Comment: what does query looks like without whereBetween ? Do you get any results ?

Comment: interesting... nothing changed.. I thought problem about "whereBetween"..

Comment: the query seems fine, check if you have any product with given category_name

Comment: Also, please show the `categories` relationship and it's structure.

Comment: @LeoinstanceofKelmendi I checked, selected category have few products

Comment: @cervantes you've shown `products` relationship, but not `categories`

Comment: @cervantes the relationship looks fine. What does `Category::where('category_name', $slug)->get();` gives you?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Sorry, I edited my question again.

Comment: with get() method give to me empty collection but with first() method, seems fine https://imgur.com/a/kgE7P

Comment: @cervantes well, it's absolutely not normal if `Category::where('category_name', $slug)->get()` returns nothing and `Category::where('category_name', $slug)->first()` returns an object. Did you override `get()` method in the `Category` model or in the base model or something? Could you also show the `Category` model?

Comment: I checked my files, everything seems normal.. as know I didin't do something like that  https://imgur.com/a/fGEwY

Comment: @cervantes the model looks fine. I can see you have `category_slug` in the table, maybe you want to use it instead of `category_name`? Your code looks fine, but the fact you're getting an object with `first()` and getting an empty collection with `get()` is super weird. It's impossible unless you've modified some built-in stuff.

Comment: You are most probably right. I started programing just seven months ago and There are a  lot of things I didn't know.  Probably I made a mistake in somewhere but I have not found it yet

Comment: What does `dd(Category::where('category_name', $slug)->count(), Category::where('category_name', $slug)->get()->count(), Category::where('category_name', $slug)->first()->category_name);` returns? Please do not modify this code, just to make sure the result will be helpful for debugging.

Comment: first one -> zero, second one -> zero too, and third one "Atque vel." (with `category_slug`) ->Trying to get property of non-object (with `category_name`) (atque vel is category name btw)

Comment: @cervantes could you install Laravel Debugbar and show raw SQL queries generated by these three queries?

Comment: Here are sql queries: https://imgur.com/a/nlhKW

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin I realized that I made a typo. `category_name` should be `category_slug`..  Now, I can get my category items but still cant get with selected price range